# PHP, Parse javascript and extract flash object!

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, parsing

I have got a list of many web page URLs.. and all of them contain videos. These videos are embed via simple HTML  and  tags. I can extract these tags by some RegEx techniques.

Now the problem is that majority of them use Javascript to embed these elements! And as they are from different websites.. They dont have any specific pattern.

The only thing i can do now is to make my "PHP execute the Javascript". And i'm stuck in this task..

I want this extraction to be done via PHP script. Ive tried jParser and jTolkenizer but i cant get it to work in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only thing i can do now is to make my "PHP execute the Javascript". And i'm stuck in this task..

Oh goodness, don't do that.  The effort you'll spend (and security problems you'll open) is going to be way, way more of a time sink than coding specific identifier code for each site that I'm blindly assuming that you're scraping.

Comment: thanks.. I believe specific identifier is the best way now :)